# tmerge to split data into 5 yearly intervals

Tags: r

I have a data set with columns: ID, follow up (days), event, variable 1, variable 2 ..

I'm trying to use tmerge to convert into 5 yearly intervals with tstart and tstop using follow up (days) as time - how do I go about this?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.